# Populate empty attribute table from constantly growing CSV in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv, table

I have a Python script running that will generate a line feature from a point depending on a degree of rotation around that point. I have a non-spatial CSV setup to get fed this rotation data from another source. The CSV will be constantly updating and generating new data, and will generate new lines in QGIS as they arrive.

As you might have inferred, I want this CSV to effectively act as a dynamic attribute table for this line feature class, but I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to perform a table join on the line feature. I have an "ID" and a "LOB" (rotation) field set up in both the CSV and the empty attribute table, so my expectation was that the tables would join and the CSV data would carry over and appear in the table. But this is not the case, as I somehow need to get the number of rows in both "ID" columns to match *prior* to the join. But this doesn't seem like a solution, as the number of columns will be rapidly changing.

Are there any reasonable solutions to this dilemma? This is very easy to do with spatial text-delimited point layers, but mind boggling with non-spatial data for lines.

Below is a screenshot for reference. The top table is the CSV, the bottom is the attribute table it's "joined" to. I need the number of rows in the attribute table to match that of the CSV.

[image: discrepant tables]